Is there a way to detect repeated sequences of words in a text?
I'm working on an ASR application and while I know I can minimize hallucinations only to a certain extent using VAD or better quality audios, there still is room for error in the transcriptions. I'm using Seamless M4T Large-V2 for transcriptions. I was thinking of making a last effort in this case, and that is by doing string manipulations on the output text. IS is possible? for example for this text,
"I'm not well, I think I wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to. Maybe tomorrow..."
I have tried using regex, but it only looks for consecutive repeated words, I'm thinking of having a variable length buffer which will detect sequences with repeated occurrences, regardless of the length (or maybe I can specify the length of the buffer).

import re

s = "I'm not well, I think I wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to. Maybe tomorrow..."

s = re.sub(r"\W+", " ", s)

pattern = r"(\w+(?:\s\w+)*?)(\s\1)+"

# Replace "*" with "{1,}" to match at least 2 words.
# pattern = r"(\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,})\s+(?=\1)"

for match in re.finditer(pattern, s, re.I):
    print(match.group(0))
    print(match.group(1))
    break

Result:
I wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to
I wont be going to

Edit
Adopting @KamilCuk 's idea to capture continuous repetitions all at once.

(?=\1) why not consume? Just \1+ consume it all, and following words. I think r"(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?)(\s+\1)+" works perfectly - matches I wont be going to 7 times.

For single words you can use "Counter" class from "collections" library:
from collections import Counter
string = "I'm not well, I think I wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to. Maybe tomorrow..."
new_list = string.split()
Counter(new_list)

Output would be:
Counter({'wont': 7,
         'be': 7,
         'going': 7,
         'to': 6,
         'i': 6,
         'I': 2,
         "I'm": 1,
         'not': 1,
         'well,': 1,
         'think': 1,
         'to.': 1,
         'Maybe': 1,
         'tomorrow...': 1})



have tried using regex, but it only looks for consecutive

Your regex maybe does. The following regex:
import re

text = "I'm not well, I think I wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to. Maybe tomorrow.."
for match in re.finditer(r"(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*?)(\s+\1)+", text, re.IGNORECASE):
    print(match.group(0))
    print(match.group(1))

Matches I wont be going to and then matches it case insentivice 7 consecutive times. You could then replace the match by a single match.

I may have an idea that could work but maybe there are some edges cases I'm not seeing.
Firstly you could try building up a graph for your text with each word being a node. Then you add a directed edge from word_A to word_B if you get the sequence "word_A word_B" in your text. If this edge already exists you could add 1 to the weight.
Then you could use an algorithm such as the DFS in order to find the cycles.
For each cycle you take the associated sequence of words and try to find if there are any contiguous repetition of that sequence. For instance, if the cycle "word_A word_B" has been found (which means that there is at least one occurrence of "word_A word_B word_A") you could try seeing if that sequence is adjacent to itself in the text.
You can do some tinkering with the weights and sort the cycles according to the highest weight in the cycle (most repeated cycle) to quickly find the most repeated ones, or only take into account the cycles that have similar weights across all edges. That will prevent cases where 2 words are often used in a sequence (A then B) and it so happens you have one occurrence of "A B A" which creates a cycle.
In any case I'm interested to see if this works, please keep me updated and good luck!

Please include some working code examples to demonstrate how your suggestions work. Thanks.

For multiple occurrence with buffer you can use the following function:
string = "I'm not well, I think I wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to. Maybe tomorrow..."
buffer_length = 2

def detect_repeated_sequences(string, buffer_length):
    new_list = string.split()
    create_buffer_list = set([" ".join(new_list[i:i+buffer_length]) for i in range(len(new_list)-buffer_length)])
    return {d:string.count(d) for d in create_buffer_list}

detect_repeated_sequences(string, buffer_length)

The output would be:
{'well, I': 1,
 'I think': 1,
 'Maybe tomorrow...': 1,
 'to i': 6,
 'wont be': 7,
 'going to': 7,
 'tomorrow...': 1,
 'be going': 7,
 "I'm not": 1,
 'going to.': 1,
 'think I': 1,
 'i wont': 6,
 'to. Maybe': 1,
 'I wont': 1,
 'not well,': 1}

If you don't need it to be case sensitive you can use this slightly modified function:
buffer_length = 5
string = "I'm not well, I think I wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to i wont be going to. Maybe tomorrow..."

def detect_repeated_sequences2(string, buffer_length):
    new_list = string.split()
    create_buffer_list = set([" ".join(new_list[i:i+buffer_length]).lower() for i in range(len(new_list)-buffer_length)])
    return {d:string.lower().count(d) for d in create_buffer_list}

detect_repeated_sequences2(string, buffer_length)

